# Hasse diagram (representation)

Tags: graph-theory

Is it possible to draw more then one Hasse diagram for one/same poset ?

$ R = \{(1,1); (2,2); (3,3); (4,4); (1,3); (1,4); (2,4); (3,4)\} $

There is no the smallest element, the greatest element is 4.

Minimal elements are 1, 2.

Maximal element is 4.

I drew two Hasse diagrams for this relation.

```
                 4                                  4
               /   \                                |
             /      \                               |
            2        3            or                3
                     /                             / \
                    /                             /   \
                 1                               1     2
```

Which of them is correct, and which not ? Where I am wrong ?

Thank you!

Comment: I updated the answer as other member noted.

Answer (score 2):

The relation $R$, as it's defined, is a partial order on the set $A=\{1,2,3,4\}$. And the diagram seems to be like:

[image]

So what you got from it is right. Indeed, $1$ and $2$ are not comparable with respect to $R$ because none of $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ are in $R$.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. Yes that's right. I wanted to draw it by a software and I am new to it. Yes the relation is transitive. Thanks

Comment: If 2 is a minimal element, why is it at the same level with 3, instead of being at same level together with 1 ?

Comment: it's due to the software i used and we know what's happened in R.

Answer (score 0):

Now, It should be like this:

```
                    4
                  /   \
                 /     \
                3       \
               /         \
              /           \
             1             2
```